# Change specific element in json file in python

Tags: python, json

I am working on a json file which consists of different data like this:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de048cd7905488bbe0e511"
  },
  "item_name": "STOCKHOLM",
  "item_type": "Sofa",
  "item_id": "302.450.44",
  "item_detail": [
    "3paxsofa",
    "seglora"
  ],
  "item_price": "18990",
  "item_count": "35",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "211 cm",
    "depth:": "88 cm",
    "height:": "80 cm",
    "heigth2:": "14 cm",
    "height3:": "72 cm",
    "depth2:": "158 cm",
    "depth3:": "59 cm",
    "height4:": "43 cm",
    "no:": "3 "
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "302.450.44",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "216 cm",
    "width: ": "92 cm",
    "height: ": "60 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "71.26 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "56.64 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "1176.0 L"
  },
  "maintenance": [
    "avoid sunset ",
    "clear with wet towel"
  ],
  "item_good": [
    "natural leather ",
    "softer leathwe ",
    "depper color and longer lifespan",
    "Niels Gammelgaard"
  ],
  "item_env": {}
}
]
```

How can I delete all the "cm" in item_size from the json file and save back to the oringinal file in order to have a better data for further usage. And getting the result like this one:

```
"item_size": {
    "width:": "211 ",
    "depth:": "88 ",
    "height:": "80 ",
    "heigth2:": "14 ",
    "height3:": "72 ",
    "depth2:": "158 ",
    "depth3:": "59 ",
    "height4:": "43 ",
    "no:": "3 "
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
data="""[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60de048cd7905488bbe0e511"
  },
  "item_name": "STOCKHOLM",
  "item_type": "Sofa",
  "item_id": "302.450.44",
  "item_detail": [
    "3paxsofa",
    "seglora"
  ],
  "item_price": "18990",
  "item_count": "35",
  "item_size": {
    "width:": "211 cm",
    "depth:": "88 cm",
    "height:": "80 cm",
    "heigth2:": "14 cm",
    "height3:": "72 cm",
    "depth2:": "158 cm",
    "depth3:": "59 cm",
    "height4:": "43 cm",
    "no:": "3 "
  },
  "item_collapsepk": {
    "product_id: ": "302.450.44",
    "pack: ": "1",
    "depth: ": "216 cm",
    "width: ": "92 cm",
    "height: ": "60 cm",
    "total_weight: ": "71.26 kg",
    "net_weight: ": "56.64 kg",
    "pack_per: ": "1176.0 L"
  },
  "maintenance": [
    "avoid sunset ",
    "clear with wet towel"
  ],
  "item_good": [
    "natural leather ",
    "softer leathwe ",
    "depper color and longer lifespan",
    "Niels Gammelgaard"
  ],
  "item_env": {}
}
]"""
myvar=json.loads(data)
for i in myvar[0]['item_size'].items():
    if 'cm' in i[1]: 
        myvar[0]['item_size'][i[0]]=i[1].replace('cm','').strip()

for i in myvar[0]['item_collapsepk'].items():
    if 'cm' in i[1]: 
        myvar[0]['item_collapsepk'][i[0]]=i[1].replace('cm','').strip()
```

1. Assumed you have only one list item, so used `myvar[0]`.
2. `i` variable is a tuple with `(Key, value)`  pair in it which we got from `.items()`.
3. `if` is written to check if the values have `cm` in it. regular expressions can be used if you have a more sophisticated scenario.
4. Assigned a new value to the same key and used the [`string replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) method to remove the `cm` from the text & used [`strip` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.strip) to remove the spaces